# How to perform carrier-doping in VASP

Tags: vasp, doping

As my question indicated, I would like to perform carrier (electron-hole) doping. Could you please guide to the right method using VASP ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`NELECT` tag](https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/NELECT) should do the trick. A number that's larger than the default value (which is automatically calculated by VASP to be the number of valence electrons in the system) gives you charge doping and a real number that's lower than the default value gives you hole doping.

Note that one doesn't necessarily needs to do a normal calculation to know the default `NELECT` value. It can be calculated manually by checking the number of valence electrons for each element in the `POTCAR` file and multiply that number of electrons with the number of corresponding atoms in the `POSCAR`.

Carrier concentration can be calculated by calculate the number of carrier you added/substracted (call it $\Delta N_\text{elect}$) divided by the volume of the unit cell ($V_\text{cell}$).

Comment: To avoid things getting too long here, I moved this discussion to the [VASP chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59325576#59325576)